Keep top six rows from a sheet then split out a file for every row after that
Every month I need to create individual trackers for each team member based off a source file that never changes location.
I have to keep the top 6 rows (all headers and descriptions of headers), and then pull in one team member's row for each new file.
Current Data:

Ideally, this is what I'm looking to see for each individual member with a way for me to output each file into a monthly folder.
Goal:

This is where I am for making the new files based on the list:
Sub CreateFolderStructure()
    Dim objRow As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = "Test"
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
        Next
        Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
    Next
End Sub


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Use images only for things that can't be demonstrated any other way, such as rendering problems with graphics. The image you posted is just wasted noise and bandwidth that adds exactly zero necessary information to the question that you haven't already explained in text.


MkDir is a VBA built-in method to create a directory. Shell command is not necessary.
Copy the activesheet to create a new workbook. Then save as new file after updating the data row.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.End property (Excel)


Workbook.SaveAs method (Excel)

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sPath As String, lastRow As Range
    Dim rowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long, rngData As Range
    Dim arrData, arrRow, oSht As Worksheet, oWK As Workbook
    Const START_ROW = 8
    Const MTH_DIR = "202406"
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MTH_DIR
    If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPath
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' ActiveSheet
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rowCnt = rngData.Rows.Count
    ColCnt = rngData.Columns.Count
    arrData = rngData.Value
    oSht.Copy
    Set oWK = ActiveWorkbook
    With oWK.Sheets(1)
        Set lastRow = .Cells(START_ROW, 1).Resize(, ColCnt)
        .Rows(START_ROW + 1 & ":" & rowCnt).Delete
        With lastRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End With
    ReDim arrRes(0, 1 To ColCnt)
    For i = START_ROW To rowCnt
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            If i > START_ROW Then
                For j = 1 To ColCnt
                    arrRes(0, j) = arrData(i, j)
                Next
                lastRow.Value = arrRes
            End If
            oWK.SaveAs sPath & arrData(i, 1) & ".xlsx"
        End If
    Next
    oWK.Close False
End Sub




One question: It looks like its getting hung up and duplicating the first row from the test section for every person. Is there a way you could make it so that it carries the entire  row across not just the name column?

Please update your screenshot with the same layout as your real data. Is TEST section a merged cell? Do you want to merge the cells on Col A in output file? eg. merge A8:A10.  it carries the entire row across not just the name column it is crucial to make sample data which has same pattern as your real data.
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Apologies for the confusion, I have updated the photo. It is not a merged cell, and nothing should be merged. I need the entirety of each members individual row in their file.

I've updated the code.
